# Poincare inequality together with Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the advection diffusion equations
$$
-\kappa \Delta u + a \cdot \nabla u = f,
$$
where $\kappa > 0$ is constant, the velocity field $a$ as constant and $f$ as the source function. In addition, suppose that we have homogeneous boundary condition (e.g. $u = 0$ on the boundary of the domain $\Omega$), then the variational formulation for this problem is: Find $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that the following holds
$$
\kappa \langle \nabla u, \nabla v\rangle +  \langle a \cdot \nabla u, v \rangle = \langle f, v \rangle
$$
for all $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$. Denote the norm associated with the space $H_0^1(\Omega)$ by $|| \cdot ||_1$, and let the norm $|| \cdot ||$ be the $L_2(\Omega)$ norm. If we set $u = v$ in the variational formulation above, we end up with the following inequality
$$
\kappa C || u ||_1^2 \le \kappa || \nabla u ||^2 = \langle f, u \rangle \le || f || \hspace{1mm} || u || \le || f || \hspace{1mm} || u ||_1.
$$

The question is, how do we achieve this? From what we can see on the left-hand-side there has been a use of Poincaré inequality to bound from below and right-hand-side is bounded by above with the help of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. But how does the equality sign hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $v=u$ gives that $$\kappa \| \nabla u \|^2+\langle a \cdot \nabla u,u \rangle = \langle f,u\rangle. $$ Then \begin{align*}
\langle a \cdot \nabla u,u \rangle &=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\int_\Omega  u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j} \, dx.
\end{align*} Since $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$, integration by parts gives $$\int_\Omega  u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j} \, dx = - \int_\Omega   \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}u \, dx .  \tag{$\ast$}  $$ Hence, $$\int_\Omega  u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j} \, dx=0 $$ for all $j=1,\dots,n$. It follows that $$ \langle a \cdot \nabla u,u \rangle =0$$ and so $$\kappa \| \nabla u \|^2 = \langle f,u\rangle $$  as required.

---

To prove ($\ast$) note that for $u \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ ($\ast$) is true. Then ($\ast$) follow from density of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ in $H^1_0(\Omega)$.